# PC communication with android through USB

Tags: android, usb, communication

I need some guidance..

I have an application (.net) on my PC (windows) that needs to send some data or file (JSON format) through USB to android tablet (4.4.2). I want to design a new app which could accept this data.

I did some research over internet and found some options to implement this but still all of it is not so clear for me:

1. My first option to do this is – port forwarding by adb shell. My PC need to have adb installed and some drivers. Is it right? Is it possible that .net exe will use this way on pc side?
2. Second option – my PC should be "USB host" and android tablet should be "USB accessory". Is it better way? And again, is it possible that .net application will implement it?
3. Last option is use WPD api.. https://github.com/geersch/WPD/blob/master/src/part-3/README.md

Which one is better?

I'll be glad to hear some clarifications on this subject or any recommendations or if there is some other way to do this.

Thanks a lot